# How to clear auto-incremented value that is assigned to a table variable in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure with a table variable containing one of the attribute as a `Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)`. In each execution, its value gets appended with the previous one.

I want to clear the value of `Id` in each execution and in every execution it should *start with 1*.

This is the code I have created

```
create procedure OnetPlus_processing 
as
begin
declare @input_data table (
  Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
  jobid int,
  title varchar(400),
  jobtitle varchar(400),
  titlerev varchar(400),
  jobtitlerev varchar(400)
)

insert into @input_data
select jobid ,title,jobtitle,titlerev,jobtitlerev
from job.dbo
left outer join .....................
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *virtual table* ? Is it a **temporary table** (`#mytable` or `##mytable`), or a **table variable** (`@mytable`) ??

Comment: Its a table variable @mytable

Answer (score 1):

You can't reset the `IDENTITY` column for a table variable. A table variable is valid in neither `DBCC CHECKIDENT` nor `TRUNCATE TABLE`, and you cannot drop that table and re-create it.

Instead of using an `IDENTITY` column, you can maybe modify the queries that are inserting into it to use a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression.

E.g. if you currently have:

```
INSERT INTO @T (Col1,Col2)
SELECT ColA,ColB from <source query> ORDER BY ColA
```

Remove the `IDENTITY` from the definition of `@T`s `ID` and use:

```
INSERT INTO @T (ID,Col1,Col2)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColA),ColA,ColB from <source query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 1)
```

It should be noted that in order to use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` you need to be `dbo (db_owner)`.

Comment: It saying "Must declare the scalar variable "@mytable"".What should I do for this ?